# MySQL order by two columns once after each other with limit?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I try, with one single SQL query, to order this query results

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC limit 20
```

by a second value, say `value2 ASC` . Only the 20 results of above query should be ordered, no other results should appear.

I tried a lot of `ODER BY` and `GROUP BY` but did not succeed.. could anyone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [subselect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) (also [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value1 DESC limit 20
) AS t ORDER BY value2 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but MySQL says "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias " ?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. Yes I'll also read the docs about subselect and subquery. Now I know the right keywords I see my question was answered here already.